# Build an .aar with all dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-build

I am building an SDK for Android that should be exported as an .aar file.

The SDK has a list of dependencies defined in its build.gradle file, for example:

```
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
```

My question is: how do i include these libraries in the .aar, so that it is self-contained and does not require the developer using it to add these libraries when using my SDK?

I have looked everywhere for this, but most answers don't seem to address this issue or don't work.

Comment: The point of maven central repository is to maintain a dependency graph and distribute each artifact separately. Your .aar will contain your own classes and a list of dependencies you mentioned. The libraries you depend on will *not* actually be bundled with your .aar. Is this clear?

Comment: It is perfectly clear. However, for scenarios that don't involve a maven based central repository, i'd like to bundle all dependencies into an SDK that is self contained. For this scenario i will want to include those dependencies.. the question is - how can i achieve that ?

Comment: Purely academically, you could obtain all the jars and aars your own aar depends on, put them in a zip file and distribute that. Does anyone actually want this from you or is this some sort of corner case you artificially made up? What if your client's app depends on a newer version of Play services? They already need Google repository for that. Who is the target consumer of this bundle? Play services depend on support libraries, you want to distribute a specific version of support libs with your bundle? Aw, hell no. Let the client's dependency management system resolve any conflicts.

Comment: We are not developing Android apps "per se". We work with a game engine that offers integration with Android (Unity3D). it does not have any gradle support, and relies on you using plugins as either .jars or .aars. It will not resolve any dependency for you. The only option to create an SDK for such a platform is either package all dependencies into your SDK, or ask the developer to find all dependencies and copy them into his project. i think the first option is the better one.

Answer (score 3):

> How do i include these libraries in the .aar

Not at all.
An `.aar`-file is not intended to contain it's own dependencies

---

You should use a dependency management system (like maven or ivy) to distribute your SDK in order to handle transitive dependencies.